# Why does half-reaction with largest positive potential will run as written while other is reversed?

Tags: redox, reduction-potential

While balancing the half redox reaction, the textbook indicated that the flip of equation is dependent on the size potential. But I do not understand the reason why it is like that. Please explain for me.

Comment: Please update your question with an example. What do you mean by "flip of  equation"? What potential?

Comment: Following @Karl , it would be helpful for you to show a fully-worked example from your textbook, complete with half reactions, standard cell potentials, net reaction, full cell potential and free energy change, with correct algebraic signs throughout.